# is there a compare folders feature in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two folders in a VS Code project and I need to compare those two folders for new, deleted or modified files.

I have seen file compare feature and third party folder compare features, but is there any native VS Code feature for folder comparison I could use. If the answer is No, then which third party plugin is considered as the best though experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## No.

As stated in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98197, VS Code does not plan on adding this feature in the near term future.

## Other options

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moshfeu.compare-folders claims to compare folders, but I can't speak to its effectiveness.

Usually I would just use `diff -r` or some type of git diff compare, as comparing a lot of files can sometimes not be a fun thing to do manually.

If both folders are git trees it becomes possible to compare them with git diff commands.

Comment: I did try the moshfew extension and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I do hope they add a feature like this soon though! They also seemed so final on the GitHub issue; perhaps someone could work a PR somehow. Grabbing random extensions makes me nervous.

Answer (score 20):

Try these:

[Diff Folders](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=L13RARY.l13-diff)

[Compare Folders](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moshfeu.compare-folders)

Comment: Compare Folders is really good! Thank you 

Answer (score 8):

I think [Diff Folders - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=L13RARY.l13-diff&ssr=false#overview) is better than [Compare Folders - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moshfeu.compare-folders):

- More intuitive.
- More clear comparison history on the sidebar.
- List the difference not only by folders but also by every file.
- You can even `copy`, `Go to file`, `Reveal in Finder` and `Delete file` directly in your Diff panel which is very convenient.
  [image]

Answer (score 5):

One possible workaround is to commit one of those folders, copy and past (merge) the other over it and use VS code source control (`Ctrl + Shift + G`). After comparison, you can use `git reset --hard` to undo the changes. But this will only show folders which contains files.

You can also try the extension on the answer above or this one:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=L13RARY.l13-diff

Answer (score 0):

Here a great workaround:

necessary: have git installed

1. create a new folder
2. copy first folder to compare into directory and commit etc
3. delete folder content except .git
4. copy second folder to compare into directory
5. `view > source control`
6. select file to see difference

See [this video](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/versioncontrol) for more information.

Comment: Yup, I just realized the above answer proposes ~~ the same thing - I'll make this an edit when there's not 'too many pending edits' anymore.